# How to open desktop application from windows service application, once receive the SignalR result

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services, signalr, hwnd

I am currently working on a windows service application that already consuming SignalR service. My new requirement is to start a desktop application when windows service receives a notification from SignalR.

While I am google on how to start a desktop application using windows service, I found [this](https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser) code base and I am currently using it.

As it explains, when I called the bellow method

```
ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCurrentUser(string path);
```

in the windows service's `OnStart` method I was able to start the desktop application.

I also have `SignalR` client in this windows service (Bellow code).

```
    public class NotificationHub
    {
        public static void ConsumeNotification()
        {
            try
            {
                var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);
                IHubProxy notificationHubHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("WSMassageHub");

                hubConnection.Start().Wait();
                notificationHubHubProxy.On<WSMessage>("SendMessage", (message) => {

                    // try to start from here 
                    // but it gives error
                    ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCurrentUser(@"D:\Application\Application.exe");
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Message: " + ex.Message + " | Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I try to start the desktop application from windows service when windows service gets the message to SignalR client.

```
protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
{
            NotificationHub.ConsumeNotification();
}
```

Once SignalR client gets a message, the application failed and error log gets this error message.

```
StartProcessAsCurrentUser: CreateProcessAsUser failed.  Error Code -2
```

According to System Error Codes, it says that The system cannot find the file specified.

Also, I suspect that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308537/3082119) will explain the issue in here. But I don't understand that which component needs to implement to start the desktop application, once SignalR client receives the notification. So, can someone please give me help hand to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the file `D:\Application\Application.exe` exist?

Comment: Yes. It is there.

Comment: Were you running this from the same computer then?

Comment: Yes. all the things in same computer

Comment: Have you tried to use other function to execute external application as [mentioned from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278705/2304737)?

Comment: [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173775/2304737)

Comment: Tried. But not working. I assume the issue in here that I am trying to start an application within SIgnalR client?

Comment: How about get a handle to your path through file and check if it exists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176229/discussion-between-nought-and-mr5).